# Robot Framework API testing - Create Session keyword not found

Tags: robotframework, robotframework-ide, robotframework-sshlibrary

I am trying to do API testing with Robot Framework as part of that,i am getting below error

No keyword with name 'createsession mysession' found.Can any body please help how to resolve this error.

I have installed below libraries.
robotframework,request,robotframework-request,robotframework-jsonlibrary

Below is the code for the same

```
===============================================================================================
*** Settings ***
Library   RequestLibrary

*** Variables ***
${baseurl}   http://demoqa.com/utilities/
${endpoint}  weather/city/

*** Keywords ***

*** Test Cases ***
TestCaseone

  createsession mysession  ${baseurl}
  ${response}=  Get Request  mysession  ${endpoint}/bangalore
  log to console  ${response.status.code}
  log to console  ${response.status.body]
  log to console  ${response.header}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your code really is formated like this:

```
createsession mysession  ${baseurl}
```

then no such keyword exists in [RequestsLibrary](https://marketsquare.github.io/robotframework-requests/doc/RequestsLibrary.html#Create%20Session).

You need to properly use whitespace, it does matter.

This should work:

`Create Session    mysession    ${baseurl}`

remember to type at least two spaces between the keyword and its arguments, and between arguments.

Comment: I tried the "Create Session  mysession  ${baseurl} still i am getting same error.Below is the output of log file                                                                                                                
Error in file 'C:\Python_Automation_Scripts\testing\RestAPIAutomation\API1.robot' on line 2: Importing test library 'RequestLibrary' failed: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'RequestLibrary'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  None
PYTHONPATH:
  C:\Python\Scripts\robot.exe
  c:\python\python39.zip

Comment: Error in file 'C:\Python_Automation_Scripts\testing\RestAPIAutomation\API1.robot' on line 2: Importing test library 'RequestLibrary' failed: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'RequestLibrary'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  None
PYTHONPATH:
  C:\Python\Scripts\robot.exe
  c:\python\python39.zip
  c:\python\DLLs
  c:\python\lib
  c:\python
  C:\Users\saravanan_s\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages
  c:\python\lib\site-packages

Comment: It says it clearly: `ModuleNotFoundError`. You need to install the library first. https://pypi.org/project/robotframework-requests/

Comment: I have already installed using pip install robotframework-requests,but still i am getting this error..Any body can help me

Answer (score 0):

Here's your code which I revised or edited
Your issue was just space hence ${baseurl} was not being recognised. Just remember to use TAB instead of space with the robotframework and inspect API to use actual words that are part of the API response.

```
  *** Settings ***
  Library   RequestsLibrary

  *** Variables ***
  ${baseurl}   http://demoqa.com/utilities/
  ${endpoint}  weather/city/

  *** Keywords ***

  *** Test Cases ***
  TestCaseone
      createsession    mysession  ${baseurl}
      ${response}=     Get On Session  mysession  ${endpoint}/bangalore
      log to console   ${response.text}
      log to console   ${response.content}
      log to console   ${response.headers}
```